# SQL Server name in connection information of Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm working on a C# application with a SQL Server 2008 database and Crystal Reports for reporting. I followed [this article](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm/) to create reports but in the step of entering connection informations I didn't know what is server name, because this is the connectionstring of my database:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True.
```

So my question is what is the server name that I should put in the connection information of Crystal Reports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a "free-floating" file-based SQL Server - really bad practice..... there's no server to connect to. I'd recommend adding this database **to a server** and then you can also reference it from Crystal Reports!

Comment: But my application doesn't need a server, it is a local application that i run i just one pc

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
rptobj.SetDatabaseLogon(DatabaseUser, DatabasePassword, SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)
```